# JMeter Proxy not recording local sites in IE 8

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I am learning JMeterProxy using WAMP and opencart web app.I did a recording using HTTP Proxy Server. I configured firefox and recording went smoothly. But if i am using IE, nothing seems to be recorded. I added a tree view listener in HTTP Proxy to log the recording, nothing is logged in it when i am using IE.

Some observations:

> 1. when i stop recording and if i try to access the local site using FF, it is not accessible, but in case of IE i could open the site.
> 2. If i browse an external site, recording is working.
> 3. I am accessing my site as `http://localhost:81/opencart/index.php`, since 80 port is used by IIS

My question is.

> 1. How would i trouble shoot this kind of scenario.
> 2. What changes i should i make in IE proxy settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem, Here is the solution, as per JMeter documentation

> If JMeter does not record browser URLs such as `http://localhost/` or
>   `"http://127.0.0.1/"`, try using the non-loopback hostname or IP address,
>   e.g. `http://myhost/` or `"http://192.168.0.2/"`

So providing the host name in place of loop back address solved the problem